# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).summernote is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

I tried [summernote](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/) as a simple html editor. I tried including summernote from cdn as shown below:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
    <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <title>Creative</title>

       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

       <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

       <!-- include summernote css/js -->
       <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="summernote" id="summernote"></div>
         <input type="button" id="dwn-btn" value="Download"/>
         <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
               $('#summernote').summernote({
                  height: 500, // set editor height
                  minHeight: null, // set minimum height of editor
                  maxHeight: null, // set maximum height of editor
                  focus: true // set focus to editable area after initializing summernote
               });

               function getCode() {
                  var html = $('#summernote').summernote("code");
                  console.log(html);
               }

               document.getElementById("dwn-btn").addEventListener("click", getCode);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Initialising summernote is working fine. But when click on download button, inside getCode function error throws as

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).summernote is not a function

While running this as code snippet its working fine. The problem is just create an html file with above code and run in browser, then the error will get in console.
Please help me, I am stuck for 2 days. For any help thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you took a look at the Network tab, is the summernote script loaded?

Comment: Yes sure, that's why the initialising function working fine. Only problem is for summernote function inside getCode method

Comment: Check `$` inside `getCode`, maybe it's not a jQuery function ..?

Comment: No, its the same line of code from the line just after `$(document).ready`

Comment: yea, thanks for the hint @Teemu. first `$` is for summernote.min.js and second `$` is for jquery.min.js. How can I make it for summernote.min.js